# Media wiki installation on a server

Tags: installation, server, mediawiki

I successfully installed media wiki on my server. However, I am not able to figure out what the URL for the wiki is. I didn't specify anything for the script path during installation, so /wiki should be it. However navigating to /wiki raises a cannot GET error. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the mediawiki from cPanel Softaculus without specifying the installation path then it will be installed  "mw" folder.

The complete path should be the following

========

/home/USERNAME/public_html/mw

Comment: I installed using the command line option provided on this page https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki using `code`(php maintenance/install.php)

Answer (score 0):

Nice urls (`/wiki`) are not enabled by default; the url is probably `/w/index.php` (just `/w` might work depending on your web server settings).

Comment: Neither worked. I installed using the command line option provided on this page https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki using `code`(php maintenance/install.php)

Comment: It is up to you to connect MediaWiki with the web server. Typically that's done by putting its files in the webroot directory, and then the URL is `/w`, but it really depends on where you put the files. It might not be reachable via web at all if the directory you put it in isn't.

Comment: I see. So, creating a symbolic link from the webroot directory to the installation directory should accomplish this right? Any idea what the paths to the webroot and the installation directories are? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's one way to do it, although that would mean that the URL will look like `/<symlink>/w`. Also, the webserver might require specific configuration to allow symlinks as they are somewhat insecure. The webroot really depends on what OS and webserver software you are using, and how it is configured (e.g. on Linux/Apache `/var/www` is a popular choice), the installation directory is wherever you put the files (and probably wherever you executed the `php...` command).